# How do you test where a character is in a text based game in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# programming, and was wondering if i am creating a text based game with 2 rooms, and the player can move between the two rooms (but not around inside them) how do you test which room the player is in? I have tried to use an if else statement, but i am not sure how to get it to go "if not in north room go there when 'Go North' is input"

Comment: what you mean room? maybe u use two different forms?

Comment: post some code chunk so that we can get what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I guess the easiest way to do that is to have a "location" property in for your characters.

```
class player 
{
    string location = "Room 1";
    ...
}
```

and then just update the location every time you move the character